# Have the writers of Star Trek: Strange New Worlds credited Ursula K. Le Guin?

Tags: star-trek, ursula-k-le-guin, copyright, star-trek-strange-new-worlds

It is difficult for me not to see Le Guin's 1973 "[The Ones Who Walk Away From Omelas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ones_Who_Walk_Away_from_Omelas)" as deeply embedded in the *ST:SNW* episode "Lift Us Above Where Suffering Cannot Reach". Both stories tell of:

- A paradisaical society predicated wholly on the suffering of a single child
- The conscious awareness of the significance and nature of this sacrifice by the other members of society
- The threat of the immediate and total end of the society should the child be spared from this suffering
- A self-exiled group of former members of the society—the 'ones who walk away' seeking something better

There are other superficial parallels—outsiders visiting the enlightened society, a sunny outdoor festival, feelings of shock and anger when first understanding the child's fate (Capt. Pike), feelings of just righteousness about the necessary sacrifice of the child (Majalis' President Alora). There are also differences (obviously): Le Guin's 'psychomyth' was not a story with plot, so much as an extremely detailed scene and ethical conundrum.

Le Guin was not credited in the title sequence, or the closing credits as far as I saw.

**Have the writers or show-runner commented on "Omelas" with respect to "Where Suffering Cannot Reach"? Did they receive permission from Le Guin's estate to use the story?**

Apparently I am [not](https://www.escapistmagazine.com/star-trek-strange-new-worlds-episode-6-review-lift-us-where-suffering-cannot-reach/) [alone](https://www.slashfilm.com/890618/the-classic-sci-fi-short-story-you-should-read-after-this-weeks-star-trek-strange-new-worlds/) [in noticing](https://www.tor.com/2022/06/09/childhoods-end-star-trek-strange-new-worlds-lift-us-where-suffering-cannot-reach/) [this](https://www.fanbyte.com/tv-film/strange-new-worlds-gets-tough-in-lift-us-where-suffering-cannot-reach/).

Comment: That might be the *right* thing to do, but then they would risk having to pay royalties to Le Guin's estate (95 years from the date of publication).

Comment: Apparently you're not alone. [The Escapist](https://www.escapistmagazine.com/star-trek-strange-new-worlds-episode-6-review-lift-us-where-suffering-cannot-reach/) mentions it. While they mostly rant about the beakness of the episode, they make the connection with _Those Who Walk Away from Omelas_.

Comment: @InTheAbsenceOfFear *Many* reviewers have noted the debt. Edited in the last line of my question.

Comment: @Lexible I actually tired of SNW halfway through last week's episode, so I have neither seen this week's episode, nor read any reviews of it, until I stumbled upon this question, and started googling.

Comment: Trekmovie.com review also makes the connection

Comment: Plagiarism is actually a high hurdle.  Just because George Lucas thought he could sue anyone with ray guns and spaceships in their stories doesn't mean it would work in court.  Likewise space tardigrades and tortured kids wouldn't be enough See Scènes à faire https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sc%C3%A8nes_%C3%A0_faire and the tardigrade case https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/ca2/19-3160/19-3160-2020-08-17.html and https://www.plagiarismtoday.com/2022/04/21/the-lawsuit-that-set-star-wars-against-battlestar-galactica/

Comment: +1 @lucasbachmann Plagiarism ≠ copyright infringement (which you may know, but I want to point out for others), and my concluding question (now bolded)  is about the latter (although I do touch on the former earlier in my question).

Comment: I deserve that correction and definitely erred.  Though I am used to thinking about Kurtzman being sued.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Kurtzman has commented on the story previously.  But it was regarding the Kelpian that caused the burn in STD not this Strange New Worlds episode.

Nitpicking Nerds' thoughts on the Discovery Episode - where ironically he points out how little it has to do with the Omelas story.

Nitpicking Nerds' repost of the interview where he jokingly titles it Strange New Worlds plagiarism.

youtube transcript

"and the idea that we needed to answer
what was responsible for this
cataclysmic event
um the idea emerged from um
a short story called those who walk away
from omalas which is
you know it's it's not really a
one-to-one analogy but
in that story a child is held captive
and tortured
so that an entire town can live in
happiness all the time
and so it raises this question of okay
well
if you could live happily and everybody
could live peacefully
with no war no strength no sickness no
nothing
except it caused one child to stay in a
permanent state of suffering would you
actually be able to be happy in that
town
right and those who walk away are the
ones who have conscience so
from that idea emerge the idea of a
child
right and the idea of how interesting it
would be if
it was an accident right that you think
you think that what is initially
presented as a monster actually isn't a
monster at all but very in fact very
human and i use human
in quotes but you know very relatable um
and that's ultimately how we kind of
circled around tsukal"

Comment: +1 It's interesting, I do not see the parallels between the *Discovery* arc and "Omelas" at all, even with his blather that you quoted.

Comment: (joke) - almost feel like mentioning the burn and the screaming kelpian is worth a downvote ;)

Comment: @Lexible Yeah basically for Discovery all Omelas did was give him the idea for a miserable kid with none of the context or ethics debate.

Comment: @NKCampbell I note many people made jokes about Kurtzman being a reverse Omelas situation in the sense we all suffer so he can be happy.

Comment: Pfffhaha. (Actually I give *Discovery* a thumbs up for the most part—like so much of the franchise—but that is funny. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if linking to a "thoughts" video adds to the answer.